# c# can't read element attribute with xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

This code can't read a specific attribute - the name attribute more specifically.
Instead it read the text of node elements and does a concat on them - result: 1F20 is added to the list

```
var reader = new StringReader(xml);
            var xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(reader);
            xmlreader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
            var doc = new XPathDocument(xmlreader);
            var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
            XPathExpression expr = nav.Compile("/Area/Lights/Light[@Name]");
            XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(expr);

            var list = new List<string>();
            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                XPathNavigator nav2 = iterator.Current.Clone();
                list.Add(nav2.Value);  
            }
```

I have also tried:
XPathExpression expr = nav.Compile("//Light[@Name]");

which returns blank

This is the xml i am trying to read:

```
<Light Index="1" SetChannel="72" GetChannel="60" Name="y1 d1">
      <Nodes>1F</Nodes>
      <Nodes>20</Nodes>
    </Light>
```

What i am doing wrong - first attempt at xpath...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is this the full XML? using your snippet here this works

```
XPathExpression expr = nav.Compile("Light/@Name");
```

just to add the usage of  `XPathExpression expr = nav.Compile("/Area/Lights/Light[@Name]");` is a filter, you are asking for a Light node that has an attribute called Name, or you may do something like `@Name = 'bob'` where you ask for a Light node with an attribute of Name equal to Bob

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to read all `Light`-elements with a `Name`-attribute.

Try `//Light[@Name='xyz']/@Name` in order to read the `Name`-attribute from the `Light`-element where `Name='xyz'` or `//Light/@Name` for all `Name`-attributes.

Remember, `[]` is for conditions.

Comment: More copy&paste errors than grammar, but thanks for editing ;D

Comment: I just *had to* correct the "Your", it gave me the creeps. :D